# sed remove last 4 characters

Tags: regex, sed

Say I have these 2 lines:

```
blah:20030717.abc
blah:20040714
```

Using sed, how can i match on both line start and end only - `^blah.*abc$` - and remove the last 4 characters?

I tried

```
sed 's/\(^blah.*\)\(.\{4\}$\)/\1/g'
```

but that removes 4 characters off the other line too.

```
blah:20030717
blah:2004
```

and

```
sed 's/\(^blah.*abc$\)\(.\{4\}$\)/\1/g'
```

doesn't change anything.

Comment: how about `sed 's/\(^blah.*\)\(\..\{3\}$\)/\1/g'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do

```
 sed 's/\.abc$//g'
```

since you already know *which*  4 characters you want to remove?

Or, if you only want to do this in lines that start with `blah:`,

```
sed 's/^\(blah.*\)\.abc$/\1/g'
```

Or, if your question is "How do I remove any final three characters after a dot, if the line starts with `blah:`":

```
sed 's/^\(blah.*\)\..\{3\}$/\1/g'
```

Comment: I guess `abc` is only an example.

Comment: @tim-pietzcker 
Wow that was fast! Thanks. Your second example is perfect
`sed 's/^\(blah.*\)\.abc$/\1/g'`
because i may also have a line of
`blah:20050723.cba`
that i want to leave as-is.